# reader.GetDouble needs int?

Tags: c#, xampp, double, mysqldatareader

I'm currently getting the total lates of an employee within a certain period in the format of `totalhours` and `double` from a database but the problem is when I check the database and lets say that the employee doesn't have a single record of late which makes `reader = null`. So, I have decided to use `isDBNull` but when i insert `if (!myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.GetDouble("total")))`, the `myReader.Getdouble("total")` generates an error with an argument that

> system cannot convert `double` to `int

```
        cc.SetCMD(@"SELECT SUM(AccHours) AS total FROM mia_payroll.tbl_late WHERE COP_ID = @ID AND EID = @EID;");
        using (myConn = new MySqlConnection(ConnectionClass.GetConnection()))
        {
            myConn.Open();
            using (cmDB = new MySqlCommand(cc.GetCMD(), myConn))
            {
                cmDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ID", lblCOID.Text);
                cmDB.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EID", EID);
                try
                {
                    using (myReader = cmDB.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (myReader.Read())
                        {
                            if (!myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.GetDouble("total")))
                            {
                                total = myReader.GetDouble("total");
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                total = 0;
                            }
                            txtLate.Text = System.Convert.ToString(total);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                }
            }
            myConn.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because `.IsDBNull()` expects an `int` ordinal position value of the column that you want to check for DBNULL. You are passing the `double` value type from `myReader.GetDouble()`. Official doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.isdbnull(v=vs.110).aspx

Simply change to `GetOrdinal`:

```
if (!myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.GetOrdinal("total")))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the column index to [IsDBNull](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlDataReader_IsDBNull.htm).

Replace `!myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.GetDouble("total"))` with:

```
!myReader.IsDBNull(myReader.GetOrdinal("total"))
```

Answer (score 0):

what's your datatype for the total field in  the database? if your field is not double then you can't parse it as double. The error clearly shows that in your database the field for hours is an int not double,